# Error: The argument type 'User?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User' because 'User?' is nullable and 'User' isn't. *(NullSafety)*

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, dart-null-safety

**I'm taking a course for Flutter and I think the course is a bit old, I'm trying to upgrade an old code to null safety, but since I'm just starting to learn null safety, I'm encountering errors and I couldn't figure out why, I would be glad if you could help.**

**"auth_event"**

```
part of 'auth_bloc.dart';

abstract class AuthEvent extends Equatable {
  const AuthEvent();

@override
  bool? get stringify => true;
  @override
 List<User?> get props => [];
}

class AuthUserChanged extends AuthEvent {
  final auth.User? user;

  const AuthUserChanged({this.user});

  @override
  List<User?> get props => [user];
}

class AuthLogoutRequested extends AuthEvent {}
```

final auth.User? user;

Context: 'user' refers to a property so it couldn't be promoted.

**"auth_state"**

```
part of 'auth_bloc.dart';

enum AuthStatus { unknown, authenticated, unauthenticated }

class AuthState extends Equatable {
  final auth.User? user;
  final AuthStatus status;

  const AuthState({
    this.user,
    this.status = AuthStatus.unknown,
  });

  factory AuthState.unknown() => const AuthState();

  factory AuthState.authenticated({required auth.User user}) {
    return AuthState(user: user, status: AuthStatus.authenticated);
  }

  factory AuthState.unauthenticated() =>
      const AuthState(status: AuthStatus.unauthenticated);

  @override
  bool? get stringify => true;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [user, status];
}
```

**"auth_bloc"**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:basla/depolar/depolar.dart';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as auth;
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

part 'auth_event.dart';
part 'auth_state.dart';

class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  final AuthRepository _authRepository;
  late StreamSubscription<auth.User?> _userSubscription;

  AuthBloc({
    @required AuthRepository authRepository,
  })  : _authRepository = authRepository,
        super(AuthState.unknown()) {
    _userSubscription =
        _authRepository.user.listen((user) => add(AuthUserChanged(user: user)));
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _userSubscription.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }

  @override
  Stream<AuthState> mapEventToState(AuthEvent event) async* {
    if (event is AuthUserChanged) {
      yield* _mapAuthUserChangedToState(event);
    } else if (event is AuthLogoutRequested) {
      await _authRepository.logOut();
    }
  }

  Stream<AuthState> _mapAuthUserChangedToState(AuthUserChanged event) async* {
    yield event.user != null
        ? AuthState.authenticated(user: event.user)
        : AuthState.unauthenticated();
  }
}
```

(user: event.user)

Error: The argument type 'User?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User' because 'User?' is nullable and 'User' isn't.

- 'User' is from 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart'

**Please alert me for codes that i need to edit..**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `authenticated` state is accepted by a not null `auth.User`. So, just update it to:

```
factory AuthState.authenticated({required auth.User? user})
```

Another solution is adding `!` to `event.user`:

```
yield event.user != null
        ? AuthState.authenticated(user: event.user!)
        : AuthState.unauthenticated();
```

Anw, you should read the documentation before you want to go any further with flutter/dart updates: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety